# Style text defined in custom data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css, custom-attributes, text-styling

I'm using a jQuery function to pull two portions of text listed in a selected image's custom data attributes, "htext" for header text and and "ptext" for paragraph text. I want to style this text so I can add line breaks and change the rags of each text bit.

Is there any easy way to do this, or would I have to redesign in order to style it as regular html text?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huL5gnej/1/

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready
$(function()
    {
    $('img').hover(function() {
       $('h5').text($(this).attr('htext'));
       $('p').text($(this).attr('ptext'));
    },function(){
       $('h5').text($('h5').data('original'));
       $('p').text($('p').data('original'));
    });

$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    slideshow: false
        });
    });

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "div.info-box, address, #fade" ).fadeIn( 2000 );
    });

$( "#slideshow" ).hover(function() {
    $( ".flex-caption" ).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
    });

})(Query);
```

HTML:

```
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/img/hover-here.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" class="img-responsive" ptext="Sustainable practices are an important consideration at Studio Green.  At this office building, permeable concrete unit pavers are used in the driveway. Storm water is collected through the joints in the pavers, where the water is directed and absorbed underground, recharging ground water, and reducing run-off. Energy-efficient LED outdoor lighting is also used.">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/img/hover-here.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" class="img-responsive" ptext="The use of materials with recycled content is another sustainable technique used at Studio Green. Steel railing has recycled content and is also recyclable, after the life of this building project. Concrete can also be specified to have recycled content, by replacing Portland cement with either fly ash or slag, both by-products of industrial processes.">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/img/hover-here.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" class="img-responsive" ptext="Studio Green regularly designs storm water treatment systems. Here a bio-swale is created adjacent to a parking lot. Storm water run-off from both the parking lot and the building roof are directed to the planters, which are planted with plants that will treat pollutants in the water. The planters serve to slow down water flow and encourage water to percolate into the soil, rather than over-tax the city's piped storm water system.">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/img/hover-here.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" class="img-responsive" ptext="Studio Green regularly uses California native plants in planting design. Native plants provide valuable habitat for native birds and insects. California native plants are also extremely well suited for landscape use because they are perfectly adapted for landscapes in California, and are often drought-tolerant and low-maintenance.">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/img/hover-here.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" class="img-responsive" ptext="Water is one of our most precious resources, and the designers at Studio Green realize the importance of designing landscapes that conserve and improve our water. Here is an example of a bio-filtration planter that is used to treat storm water run-off from a building roof.">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/img/hover-here.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" class="img-responsive" ptext="Studio Green understands the use of micro-climate appropriate plantings    to both beautify and rehabilitate landscapes. Here the use of low-water requiring, native plants supports habitat for wildlife and pollinators.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-box office-box pull-right">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right gob"></span>
                <div class="change-box">
                    <p data-original="Studio Green understands the use of micro-climate appropriate plantings to both beautify and rehabilitate landscapes. Here the use of low-water requiring, native plants supports habitat for wildlife and pollinators.">Studio Green understands the use of micro-climate appropriate plantings to both beautify and rehabilitate landscapes. Here the use of low-water requiring, native plants supports habitat for wildlife and pollinators.</p>
                </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.elements-add {
    margin-right: 15px !important;
}

.office-box {
    width: 225px !important;
}

.info-box {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.change-box {
    height: 220px;
}

.info-box h5 {
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *.html()* instead of *.text()* and use HTML markup.